# How to pass dynamic JSON data in Jmeter while doing performance Testing?

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm new to Jmeter, and working on load test, I did couple of samples and that are running fine, Now I'm facing a Issue at below point.

Issue: How do I pass the variable in JSON body part?for few request we've a body and the body should change as per the input data, Ex: username and email, etc,.

I used ${name} kind of variable in Jmeter, but it's not working. Could you please suggest us the better way to rid out this issue.

Note: Please, refer the screenshot, where I wants to put a variable and that should come from user defined variables.
[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEyrm.png)

Thanks in Advance,
Rajesh B

Jmeter version: 5.1
Windows 10

{
  "unitNumber": "111",
  "bathRooms": 1,
  "price": 50,
  "basePrice": 50,
  "streetAddress": "${ADDRESS}",
  "city": "Washington",
  "state": "CO",
  "address": "${ADDRESS_2}",
  "addressId": 2,
  "contactPreferedValue": "Email",
  "weekSelected": "1",
  "cleaningWeekSelected": "1",
  "email": "${Email}",
  "mobile": "",
  "weekSelectedValue": "May 30 2019",
  "keypadPasscode": false,
  "contactValue": "I'll be at home",
  "contactPrefered": 1,
  "isPaymentDone": false
}

Expected result: Jmeter Script (JSON Body) should allow to read dynamic data from user defined variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check you plan is same as below:-

[image]
[image]

Hope this help.

**Update:-**
It is the same logic. I have used your json in http request body and used user defined variable. I have got the below output.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see that you've passed user defined variables and that is reflecting in response body, But I'd like to know for the request body, in the request body I want to pass the variable (In JSON Request body). Could you please suggest.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this, It might work now. I'll do it now, and get back you.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON Extractor from Post Processor to parse the JSON and store the value in a variable. Once you do that you can use the variable in required places

Please check the link bellow for details
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor